# Ignoring other USB devices in a udev rule?

Tags: linux, usb, udev

Is it possible to create a udev rule for an USB device and ignore other USB devices?

I want my system to support HID USB touchscreen (hid.ko) and ignore HID devices such as keyboards, mice, etc.

Answer (score 6):

By the time udev is running to handle creating the device, it's too late—the kernel has already attached the HID driver to the mouse/keyboard/etc.

Instead, you should be able to use the [USB authorization framework](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/usb/authorization.txt) (I've personally never used this, so I can't vouch it works). Basically, you tell Linux not to authorize new USB devices. Then you individually authorize each one by doing `echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/DEVICE/authorized` as root.

You can set the default to not authorized via the `usbcore` `authorized_default=0` module parameter or the `usbcore.authorized_default=0` kernel parameter (if USB isn't compiled as a module). Alternatively, you can do it on a per-bus basis, after boot, with `echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/authorized_default`.

Answer (score 0):

There was an option called `ignore_device`, but it no longer exists. From the changelog,

> **remove `ignore_device`** There is no way to ignore an event these days. Libudev events can not be suppressed. It only prevents RUN keys from being executed,
>   which results in an inconsistent behavior in current setups.