# Restrict peripherals to input/output devices

Tags: security, peripherals

I have some Linux Debian machines that I want to prevent "unauthorized" devices from being plugged in. Basically I don't want employees plugging in external hard drives or USB thumb drives and moving data onto or off of the machines.

I would like to disable all the USB ports on the machine, but then I would have no way to plug in a keyboard and mouse. In the old days the mouse and keyboard plugged into PS/2 slots which were separate from the USB, but now all ordinary mice and keyboards are USB.

Is there any way I can allow just a mouse and keyboard and prevent all other access to the machine?

Comment: Related questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110418/22142 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222153/22142 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111696/22142